# Encaixar DIV de forma automatica com CSS

Tags: html, css

Olá

Eu estou tentando fazer s div's se encaixarem de forma automatica um ao lado da outra e caso não haja espaço do lado vais e encaixando de forma automatica da esquerda para a direita, mas não esta funcionando.

OBS: Oque determina o formato da DIV é a imagem que vai dentro dela.

Segue meu codigo e a imagem de como eu quero fazer.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo HTML

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
   <style>
   article .tile {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   box-sizing: border-box;

   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;

   font-size: 3em;
   font-weight: 700;

   padding: 0 6px;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;

   border:1px dotted black;
 }

 article .tile.wide {
   width: 200px;
 }

 article .tile.tall {
   height: 200px;
 }

.tile.yellow { background: yellow; }
.tile.red { background: red; }
.tile.blue { background: blue; }
.tile.black { background: black; }
.tile.grey { background: grey; }
.tile.green { background: green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<article>
<div class="tile blue"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="tile black"><p>2</p></div>
<div class="tile yellow"><p>3</p></div>
<div class="tile grey"><p>4</p></div>
<div class="tile red"><p>5</p></div>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado

Comment: Me pareceu simples o questionamento, mas posso ter entendido errado.
Neste caso um exemplo seria uma div.container com width: 600px; Height: Auto; padding: 10px(se necessário) - E as div's.box com float: left; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 2px; margin: 5px;

Se for realmente isso posso lhe responder pois as box teriam espaçamentos automáticos e ficaria flutuantes da esquerda para direita, se exceder o espaço do container pula pra baixo e aumenta o height do container.

Answer (score 0):

Como descrito no comentário, precisa adicionar atributos certos no container. Pode ser assim também:

```
article {
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar de uma 'forçinha' do JS. Pode utilizar a biblioteca http://masonry.desandro.com/, te recomendo esta biblioteca por ser a mais utilizada e vai te garantir um correto funcionamento na sua aplicação e em todos os browsers modernos. Para fazer isso apenas com **html** e **css** de forma automática fica inviável.

> Segue o github do criador com a documentação
>   https://github.com/desandro/masonry

. É simples, também posso te ajudar se precisar...

Abraços.

Comment: Boa dica Adriano, Obrigado. Eu gostei de um exemplo que tem no site do desenvolvedor, mas pedi para exibir o codigo fonte, mas esta cheio de javascript solto dentro dele, não entendi nada, você poderia me ajudaria com um exemplo simples, parecido com esse exemplo: http://www.erikjohanssonphoto.com/work